# pyinstaller .exe build stops right after start with no errors

Tags: python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller, neat

Im new to the world of algorithms. I created my first NEAT AI using python. This was originally for a school project, but the school doesn't let us install any software on the computers. Therefore, I wanted to make a .exe file from a .py file. I've done this several times, this time it didn't work though. I'm guessing it's because it has NEAT involved. In case anybody is interested, here's the code I use(flappy bird with AI):

```
import pygame
import neat
import time
import os
import random
pygame.font.init()

WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800

GEN = 0

BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("bird1.png")), 
pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("bird2.png")), 
pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("bird3.png"))]

PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("pipe.png"))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("base.png"))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("bg.png"))

STAT_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", 50)

class Bird:
IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
MAX_ROTATION = 25
ROT_VEL = 25
ANIMATION_TIME = 5

def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.tilt = 0
    self.tick_count = 0
    self.vel = 0
    self.height = self.y
    self.img_count = 0
    self.img = self.IMGS[0]

def jump(self):
    self.vel = -10.5
    self.tick_count = 0
    self.height = self.y

def move(self):
    self.tick_count += 1

    d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2

    if d >= 16:
        d = 16

    if d < 0:
        d -= 2

    self.y = self.y + d

    if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
        if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION: 
            self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
    else:
        if self.tilt > -90:
            self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

def draw(self, win):
    self.img_count += 1

    if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]
    elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
        self.img = self.IMGS[1]
    elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
        self.img = self.IMGS[2]
    elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
        self.img = self.IMGS[1]
    elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4 + 1:
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        self.img_count = 0

    if self.tilt <= -80:
        self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft= (self.x, self.y)).center)
    win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

def get_mask(self):
    return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)


class Pipe:
GAP = 200
VEL = 5

def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
    self.height = 0

    self.top = 0
    self.bottom = 0
    self.PIPE_TOP = pygame.transform.flip(PIPE_IMG, False, True)
    self.PIPE_BOTTOM = PIPE_IMG

    self.passed = False
    self.get_height()

def get_height(self):
    self.height = random.randrange(50, 450)
    self.top = self.height - self.PIPE_TOP.get_height()
    self.bottom = self.height + self.GAP

def move(self):
    self.x -= self.VEL

def draw(self, win):
    win.blit(self.PIPE_TOP, (self.x, self.top))
    win.blit(self.PIPE_BOTTOM, (self.x, self.bottom))

def collide(self, bird):
    bird_mask = bird.get_mask()
    top_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_TOP)
    bottom_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.PIPE_BOTTOM)

    top_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.top - round(bird.y))
    bottom_offset = (self.x - bird.x, self.bottom - round(bird.y))

    b_point = bird_mask.overlap(bottom_mask, bottom_offset)
    t_point = bird_mask.overlap(top_mask, top_offset)

    if t_point or b_point:
        return True

    return False

class Base:
VEL = 5
WIDTH = BASE_IMG.get_width()
IMG = BASE_IMG

def __init__(self, y):
    self.y = y
    self.x1 = 0
    self.x2 = self.WIDTH

def move(self):
    self.x1 -= self.VEL
    self.x2 -= self.VEL

    if self.x1 + self.WIDTH < 0:
        self.x1 = self.x2 + self.WIDTH

    if self.x2 + self.WIDTH < 0:
        self.x2 = self.x1 + self.WIDTH

def draw(self, win):
    win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x1, self.y))
    win.blit(self.IMG, (self.x2, self.y))


def draw_window(win, birds, pipes, base, score, gen):
win.blit(BG_IMG, (0,0))

for pipe in pipes:
    pipe.draw(win)

text = STAT_FONT.render("Pontok: " + str(score), 1, (255,255,255))
win.blit(text, (WIN_WIDTH - 10 - text.get_width(), 10))

text = STAT_FONT.render("Generáció: " + str(gen), 1, (255,255,255))
win.blit(text, (10, 10))

base.draw(win)
for bird in birds:
    bird.draw(win)

pygame.display.update()

def main(genomes, config):
global GEN 
GEN += 1
nets = []
ge = []
birds = []

for _, g in genomes:
    net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
    nets.append(net)
    birds.append(Bird(230, 350))
    g.fitness = 0
    ge.append(g)

score = 0
base = Base(730)
pipes = [Pipe(600)]
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run: 
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pipe_ind = 0
    if len(birds) > 0:
        if len(pipes) > 1 and birds[0].x > pipes[0].x + pipes[0].PIPE_TOP.get_width():
            pipe_ind = 1
    else:
        run = False
        break

    for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
        bird.move()
        ge[x].fitness += 0.1

        output = nets[x].activate((bird.y, abs(bird.y - pipes[pipe_ind].height), abs(bird.y - pipes[pipe_ind].bottom)))

        if output[0] > 0.5:
            bird.jump()

    add_pipe = False
    rem = []
    base.move()
    for pipe in pipes:
        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):        
            if pipe.collide(bird):
                ge[x].fitness -= 1
                birds.pop(x)
                nets.pop(x)
                ge.pop(x)

            if not pipe.passed and pipe.x < bird.x:
                pipe.passed = True
                add_pipe = True

        if pipe.x + pipe.PIPE_TOP.get_width() < 0:
            rem.append(pipe)

        pipe.move()

    if add_pipe:
        score += 1
        for g in ge:
            g.fitness += 5
        pipes.append(Pipe(600))

    for r in rem:
        pipes.remove(r)

    for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
        if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() >= 730 or bird.y < 0:
            birds.pop(x)
            nets.pop(x)
            ge.pop(x)

    draw_window(win, birds, pipes, base, score, GEN)

def run(config_path):
config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, 
neat.DefaultStagnation, config_path)

p = neat.Population(config)
p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
p.add_reporter(stats)

winner = p.run(main,20)

if __name__ == "__main__":
local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, "config_feedforward.txt")
run(config_path)
```

When I run the .exe file, the console appears, and shows:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

And then stops.

when I run the .py file, it starts the AIs normally and says something like:

```
******* Running Generation 1 *******
```

The pyinstaller command I use:

```
pyinstaller --onefile game.py
```

I didnt find any solutions to this yet, and I've been browsing for 2 days.

I get no errors when running it from cmd. I also get some "hidden import not found" warnings in pyinstaller while building but I don't think that should be a problem.

I've tried by referencing the /imgs library and config-feedforward.txt but it didn't work that way either. Any help is appreciated. Sorry for any typos or bad english.

Have a nice day!